# Which additional features to use apart from Doc2Vec embeddings for Document Similarity?

Tags: nlp, data-science, doc2vec, sentence-similarity

So I am doing a project on document similarity and right now my features are only the embeddings from Doc2Vec. Since that is not showing any good results, after hyperparameter optimization and word embedding before the doc embedding... What other features can I add, so as to get better results?
My dataset is 150 documents, 500-700 words each, with 10 topics(labels), each document having one topic. Documents are labeled on a document level, and that labeling is currently used only for evaluation purposes.

Edit: The following is answer to gojomo's questions and elaborating on my comment on his answer:

The evaluation of the model is done on the training set. I am comparing if the label is the same as the most similar document from the model. For this I am first getting the document vector using the model's method 'infer_vector' and then 'most_similar' to get the most similar document. The current results I am getting are 40-50% of accuracy. A satisfactory score would be of at least 65% and upwards.

Due to the purpose of this research and it's further use case, I am unable to get a larger dataset, that is why I was recommended by a professor, as this is a university project, to add some additional features to the document embeddings of Doc2Vec. As I had no idea what he ment, I am asking the community of stackoverflow.

The end goal of the model is to do clusterization of the documents, again the labels for now being used only for evaluation purposes.

If I don't get good results with this model, I will try out the simpler ones mentioned by @Adnan S @gojomo such as TF-IDF, Word Mover's Distance, Bag of words, just presumed I would get better results using Doc2Vec.

Answer (score 2):

You should try creating TD-IDF with 2 and 3 grams to generate a vector representation for each document. You will have to train the vocabulary on all the 150 documents. Once you have the TF-IDF vector for each document, you can use cosine similarity between any two of them.

Here is a [blog article](https://medium.com/machine-learning-intuition/document-classification-part-2-text-processing-eaa26d16c719) with more details and [doc page for sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will try this as a second method if I don't get good results. My question was whether I can create any additional features to the Doc2Vec document vectors but I will take this into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

How are you evaluating the results as not good, and how will you know when your results are adequate/good?

Note that just 150 docs of 400-700 words each is a tiny, tiny dataset: typical datasets used published `Doc2Vec` results include tens-of-thousands to millions of documents, of hundreds to thousands of words each.

It will be hard for any of the `Word2Vec`/`Doc2Vec`/etc-style algorithms to do much with so little data. (The gensim `Doc2Vec` implementation includes a similar toy dataset, of 300 docs of 200-300 words each, as part of its unit-testing framework, and to eke out even vaguely useful results, it must up the number of training epochs, and shrink the vector size, significantly.)

So if intending to use `Doc2Vec`-like algorithms, your top priority should be finding more training data. Even if, in the end, only ~150 docs are significant, collecting more documents that use similar domain language can help improve the model.

It's unclear what you mean when you say there are 10 topics, and 1 topic per document. Are those human-assigned categories, and are those included as part of the training texts or tags passed to the `Doc2Vec` algorithm? (It might be reasonable to include it, depending on what your end-goals and document-similarity evaluations consist of.)

Are these topics the same as the labelling you also mention, and are you ultimately trying to predict the topics, or just using the topics as a check of the similarity-results?

As @adnan-s suggests in the other answer, it may also be worth trying more-simple count-based 'bag of words' document representations, including potentially on word n-grams or even character n-grams, or TF-IDF weighted.

If you have adequate word-vectors, as trained from your data or from other compatible sources, the "Word Mover's Distance" measure can be another interesting way to compute pairwise similarities. (However, it may be too expensive to calculate between many-hundred-word texts - working much faster on shorter texts.)

Comment: I am evaluating the model by comparing if the labels match, between a document from the training set and the most similar to it. The results are 40%-50% and a  satisfactory score would be of at least 70%. This is the sole reason for the labels.

I've read that Doc2Vec and similar models as you say are meant for larger datasets, but at the moment I am unable to find more data because of the dataset being specific and the model's further usecase.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already suggested your training set of 150 documents probably isn't big enough to create good representations. You could, however, try to **use a pre-trained model** and infer the vectors of your documents.

Here is a [link](https://ibm.ent.box.com/s/3f160t4xpuya9an935k84ig465gvymm2) where you can download a (1.4GB) DBOW model trained on English Wikipedia pages, working with 300-dimensional document vectors. I obtained the link from [jhlau/doc2vec](https://github.com/jhlau/doc2vec) GitHub repository. After downloading the model you can use it as follows:

```py
from gensim.models import Doc2Vec

# load the downloaded model
model_path = "enwiki_dbow/doc2vec.bin"
model = Doc2Vec.load(model_path)

# infer vector for your document
doc_vector = model.infer_vector(doc_words)
```

Where *doc_words* is a list of words in your document.

This, however, may not work for you in case your documents are very specific. But you can still give it a try.